# Unity hub не создаёт/открывает проект, что делать?

Tags: unity3d

не создаётся проект в Unity hub(лицензия есть, версия 2019 и 2021). вот логи:[логи](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MRXAmLc9uLxRR93ABurz_yyBNiFfC2Kp/view?usp=sharing)

ТЕХ ПОДДЕРЖКА ИГНОРИТ, я и на русском и на английском писал.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: ТЕХ поддержка игнорит, прошло уже более 19 дней .(с того момента как я им написал)

Comment: судя по логу - оператор (или кто там заведует интернетом) блокирует часть запросов. А сам проект (и похоже его шаблон) - поврежден.\

Comment: @KoVadim как можно пофиксить шаблон? может ли Брандмауэр блокировать запросы?

Comment: Может. Как фиксить - а кто его знает, причина блокировки мне непонятна.

Comment: @KoVadim если вдруг что-то узнаете, напишите. Пока буду искать решение.

Comment: Я бы попробовал поменять провайдера. Ч

Comment: @KoVadim поменял. Версию хаба тоже установил заведомо рабочий. Всё так же

Comment: тогда у меня только это остается https://blog.unity.com/news/we-stand-with-ukraine - но там нет деталей

Comment: @KoVadim если ты про то что у меня санкции. То я вообще в Швеции живу, поэтому я уже не знаю что делать (

Comment: это была попытка. Тогда лучше мучать саппорт дальше